How to select a drop-down list in Eclipse rcptt
How to select a dropdown list with eclipse rcptt.
There is a label called "menu" and only one drop-down is present I,e ."basic" in the drop-down list which I have to select for desktop automation. Please provide the solution
I have tried the below syntax, but this is not working.
get-editbox -after [get-label "menu" ] | set-text basic
Please provide the solution
